# Trouble with Seeding data in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, seeding, asp.net-core-6.0

I am currently having problem while trying to seed my data in ASP.NET Core 6. After running the application, I don't see any data updated in my database. Below is my code for `DbInitializer.cs` and `Program.cs`.

This is my `DbInitializer.cs` file:

```
using e_commerce.Models;

namespace e_commerce.Data
{
    public class DataSeeder
    {
        private readonly ShopDbContext shopDbContext;

        public DataSeeder(ShopDbContext shopDbContext)
        {
            this.shopDbContext = shopDbContext; 
        }  

        public void Seed()
        {
                if (!shopDbContext.Users.Any())
                {
                    var User_List = new List<User>()
                    {
                        new User()
                        {
                            UserId = 1,
                            FirstName = "David", 
                            LastName = "D",
                            Email = "davidd.com",
                            Password = "1234"
                        },

                        new User()
                        {
                            UserId=2, 
                            FirstName = "Alex",
                            LastName = "S",
                            Email="alexs@gmail.com",
                            Password="1234"
                        }
                    };
                    shopDbContext.Users.AddRange(User_List);
                    shopDbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                //Products
                List<Product_Seller> MacBook_Sellers = new List<Product_Seller>();
                Product_Seller macbook_seller_1 = new Product_Seller();
                macbook_seller_1.SellerID = 1;
                macbook_seller_1.ProductID = 1;
                Product_Seller macbook_seller_2 = new Product_Seller();
                macbook_seller_2.SellerID = 2;
                macbook_seller_2.ProductID = 1;
                MacBook_Sellers.Add(macbook_seller_1);
                MacBook_Sellers.Add(macbook_seller_2);
  // adding elements using add() method
                
                if (!shopDbContext.Products.Any())
                {
                    var Product_list = new List<Product>()
                    {
                        new Product()
                        {
                            ProductID = 1,
                            ProductName = "Macbook Pro 2022",
                            ProductImageUrl = "https://i.ibb.co/7nWnHc7/macbookpro.jpg",
                            ProductPrice = 2000.00,
                            Products_Sellers = MacBook_Sellers
                        },
                        new Product()
                        {
                            ProductID = 2, 
                            ProductName = "Dell XPS",
                            ProductImageUrl = "https://i.ibb.co/KXxJsfM/dellxps.jpg",
                            ProductPrice = 1999.00,
                            SellerID = 2
                        }

                    };
                    shopDbContext.Products.AddRange(Product_list);
                    shopDbContext.SaveChanges();

                }
                //Sellers
                List<Product_Seller> store_1_product = new List<Product_Seller>();
                Product_Seller product1 = new Product_Seller();
                product1.SellerID = 1;
                product1.ProductID = 1;
                Product_Seller product2 = new Product_Seller();
                product2.SellerID = 1;
                product2.ProductID = 2;
                store_1_product.Add(product1);
                store_1_product.Add(product2);

                if (!shopDbContext.Sellers.Any())
                {
                    var Seller_list = new List<Seller>()
                    {
                        new Seller()
                        {
                            SellerId = 1,
                            SellerFirstName = "Da",
                            SellerLastName = "Du",
                            SellerEmail = "abcd@gmail.com",
                            SellerPassword = "1234",
                            SellerPhone = 1900,
                            SellerReview = 5,
                            Products_Sellers = store_1_product

                        },

                        new Seller()
                        {
                            SellerId = 2, 
                            SellerFirstName = "Ng",
                            SellerLastName = "Le",
                            SellerEmail = "bcdez@gmail.com",
                            SellerPassword = "1234",
                            SellerPhone = 1800,
                            SellerReview = 5, 
                            ProductID = 1
                        }
                    } ;
                    shopDbContext.Sellers.AddRange(Seller_list);
                    shopDbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And this is my `Program.cs` file

```
using e_commerce.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ShopDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddTransient<DataSeeder>();
//can be placed among other "AddScoped" - above: var app = builder.Build();   

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//seed 

app.Run();
if (args.Length == 1 && args[0].ToLower() == "seeddata")
    SeedData(app);

//Seed Data
void SeedData(IHost app)
{
    var scopedFactory = app.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

    using (var scope = scopedFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataSeeder>();
        service.Seed();
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you get some error messages? Could  you share your code of your model ?

Comment: I did not get any error messages because I just ran the application and the web page seemed fine.

Comment: Have you set any Breakpoint in SeedData to check if the project can access into this method successfully?

Comment: I tried to put the break points in SeedData, DbInitializer and also in the HomeController but it only got step in to the HomeController. It never seemed to reach the other two.

Comment: Run delegates don't receive a next parameter. The first Run delegate is always terminal and terminates the pipeline,So if you call SeedData(app) after app.run(),the codes will never be executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do some change based on your code. And I get the data in the database.

Seller

```
public class Seller
    {
        public int SellerId { get; set; }

        public string SellerFirstName { get; set; }

        public string SellerLastName { get; set; }

        public string SellerEmail { get; set; }


        public string SellerPassword { get; set; }

        public int SellerPhone { get; set; }

        public int SellerReview { get; set; }

        //Relationships

        public List<Product_Seller> Products_Sellers { get; set; }
    }
```

Product

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; }

        public double ProductPrice { get; set; }

        //Relationships

        public List<Product_Seller> Products_Sellers { get; set; }

    }
```

ShopDbContext

```
public class ShopDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<ShopDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Product_Seller> Products_Sellers { get; set; }


        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Product_Seller>().HasKey(i => new { i.ProductID, i.SellerID });
        }
    }
```

DataSeeder

```
 public class DataSeeder
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            using (var shopDbContext = new ShopDbContext(
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<
                    DbContextOptions<ShopDbContext>>()))
            {

                if (!shopDbContext.Users.Any())
                {
                    var User_List = new List<User>()
                    {
                        new User()
                        {

                            FirstName = "David",
                            LastName = "D",
                            Email = "davidd.com",
                            Password = "1234"
                        },

                        new User()
                        {

                            FirstName = "Alex",
                            LastName = "S",
                            Email="alexs@gmail.com",
                            Password="1234"
                        }
                    };
                    shopDbContext.Users.AddRange(User_List);
                    shopDbContext.SaveChanges();
                }


                if (!shopDbContext.Products.Any() && !shopDbContext.Sellers.Any())
                {

                    var product1 = new Product()
                    {

                        ProductName = "Macbook Pro 2022",
                        ProductImageUrl = "https://i.ibb.co/7nWnHc7/macbookpro.jpg",
                        ProductPrice = 2000.00

                    };
                    var product2 = new Product()
                    {

                        ProductName = "Dell XPS",
                        ProductImageUrl = "https://i.ibb.co/KXxJsfM/dellxps.jpg",
                        ProductPrice = 1999.00

                    };
                    var seller1 = new Seller()
                    {

                        SellerFirstName = "Da",
                        SellerLastName = "Du",
                        SellerEmail = "abcd@gmail.com",
                        SellerPassword = "1234",
                        SellerPhone = 1900,
                        SellerReview = 5


                    };

                    var seller2 = new Seller()
                    {

                        SellerFirstName = "Ng",
                        SellerLastName = "Le",
                        SellerEmail = "bcdez@gmail.com",
                        SellerPassword = "1234",
                        SellerPhone = 1800,
                        SellerReview = 5

                    };


                    var pslist = new List<Product_Seller>()
            {
                new Product_Seller() { Product = product1, Seller = seller1 },
                new Product_Seller() { Product = product1, Seller = seller2 },

       
                new Product_Seller() { Product = product2, Seller = seller1 },

            };
                    shopDbContext.Products_Sellers.AddRange(pslist);

                    shopDbContext.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Program

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using seed3Many.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ShopDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    DataSeeder.Initialize(services);
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need call SeedData(app) before app.Run() and other middleware which need the  data in database

I tried as below in .net 5(a bit different from .net 6)

Created a  static class to initialize the dbcontext:

```
public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(UserDbtestContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            if (context.User.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }
            var users = new List<User>()
            {
                new User(){Email="email",FirstName="firstname1",LastName="lastname1",Password="password"},
                new User(){Email="email",FirstName="firstname2",LastName="lastname2",Password="password"},
                new User(){Email="email",FirstName="firstname2",LastName="lastname2",Password="password"}
            };
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                context.User.Add(user);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

modified SeedData method in .net 5,you don't need to modify this method in your code

```
 void SeedData(IApplicationBuilder app)
            {
                var scopedFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
    
                using (var scope = scopedFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var dbcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserDbtestContext>();
                    DbInitializer.Initialize(dbcontext);
                }
            }
```

called SeedData(app) before other middleware,
The result:
[image]